# GMail API iOS Authorization

Tags: ios, swift, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API in iOS with the code that is given on the link

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift

and I tried running the application on an iPhone but every time, when I start the application it is asking for a Google login for authorization.

The page at Google Developers says that:
    Authorization information is stored in your Keychain, so subsequent executions will not prompt for authorization.

So my question is that for my application is the Keychain value not being stored, if so how can I correct it and if not what can be the possible error in the code that is in the link provided above?

Comment: Didn't you post this twenty minutes ago under a different user name? (Edit: Ah, no, it seems it was [someone else.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658756/ios-gmail-api-unable-store-keychain-value) SO really is a village)